# how to find entries with no tags using acts-as-taggable-on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

What's the Right Way(tm) to find the entries that have no tags?

I tried using `Entry.tagged_with(nil)` but it just returns an empty hash.

I need it so I can list the entries I still need to tag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the internals of acts-as-taggable-on I can't think of a neat way that doesn't involve looping queries or raw SQL. This is readable:

```
need_to_tag = []

Entry.all.each do |e|
  need_to_tag << e if e.tag_list.blank?
end
```

need_to_tag then holds any untagged Entries.

Comment: thanks. I hoped there would be a better way but this certainly works too.

Comment: is there a better method? this makes one query hit to the database. I have like 5000 records tagged and this unacceptable.

Comment: I think that the best method for you is going to be to use a raw SQL query in that case.

Comment: ... and server crashes in cause of memory out. First time when get 100000 of entries and second time when need_to_tag will have 50000 entries.

Answer (score 4):

The following seems to work for me:

```
Entry.includes("taggings").where("taggings.id is null")
```

This should support chaining as well. For example, the following should work:

```
Entry.includes("taggings").where("taggings.id is null").where(foo: "bar")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution to find the tagged and untagged photos.

```
scope :with_taggings, where('id in (select taggable_id from taggings where taggable_type = ’Photo‘ and context = ’bibs‘)')
scope :without_taggings, where('id not in (select taggable_id from taggings where taggable_type = ’Photo‘ and context = ’bibs‘)')
```

But it works for the Photo model, but can not be chained with other scopes.

Comment: Two remarks: a) You should use single ' in SQL code. MySQL treats "'" and '"' the same, but other databases (e.g. Postgresql) don't. b) Without playing with that - why can this code not be chained?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is ancient but I just came on a similar need today.  I just did it with a simple multiple-query scope:

```
scope :untagged, lambda {
  # first build a scope for the records of this type that *are* tagged
  tagged_scope = Tagging.where(:taggable_type => base_class.to_s)

  # only fetching the taggable ids
  tagged_scope = tagged_scope.select('DISTINCT taggable_id')

  # and use it to retrieve the set of ids you *don't* want
  tagged_ids = connection.select_values(tagged_scope.to_sql)

  # then query for the rest of the records, excluding what you've found
  where arel_table[:id].not_in(tagged_ids)
}
```

It may not be efficient for huge datasets but it suits my purposes.