# find entries with no tags using acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

There's an answer to my question - [how to find entries with no tags using acts-as-taggable-on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574559/how-to-find-entries-with-no-tags-using-acts-as-taggable-on)

but is unfortunately highly inefficient. It makes one hit to the db during the loop

I have 10,000 records, and if im going to loop through all them and the code hits one query for all 10k, it will be unacceptable.

looking for a more efficient solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest this solution (example for model Candidate):

```
Candidate.all - Candidate.joins("JOIN taggings on taggings.taggable_id = candidates.id").where("taggings.taggable_type = 'Candidate'")
```

This hit database only two times, no matter how many objects you have in your table.

Answer (score 3):

My Solution for this as a scope is:

```
scope :no_tags, joins('LEFT JOIN taggings ON taggings.taggable_id = assets.id AND taggings.taggable_type = "Asset"').where('taggings.id IS NULL')
```